# Possible to style Google Maps SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is it possible to style the map in Google Maps SDK for iOS like in Google Maps API used in web pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not yet possible to style the map in the iOS SDK. Please file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request).